# Gnuplot Multi Column fit (not Multi-branch)

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I have data files "y.csv" which contains several runs (data sets) of an experiment in columns that I want to simultaneously fit to a single function.  It should work like  `plot for [i=2:*] "y.csv" using 1:i`
to automatically accomodate however many columns are in the file.  Here is a short example data file:-

```
,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
01,,,,,,,
02,0.2200,0.2200,0.2080,0.2170,0.1530,,
03,0.2720,0.3230,0.2530,0.2380,0.2620,,
04,0.3900,0.3790,0.3770,0.3760,0.3500,,
05,0.5520,0.5600,0.5450,0.4830,0.4870,,
06,0.6640,0.6300,0.6830,0.6030,0.6520,,
07,0.6440,0.6900,0.6360,0.5960,0.6520,,
08,0.6030,0.6470,0.6190,0.6300,0.6280,,
09,0.5450,0.5890,0.5860,0.6830,0.5540,,
10,0.6370,0.6430,0.5800,0.5270,0.6180,,
11,0.6400,0.5600,0.7190,0.6780,0.7420,,
12,,,,,,,
```

I can automatically plot each of these columns, overlooking column headers, etc with:-

```
  set datafile separator ","
  set datafile columnheaders
  set key autotitle columnheader
  set key top left
  set key title "Run"
  set xrange [1:12]
  set xlabel "Dilution (Proportional to log([]) )"
  set ylabel "Response"
  plot for [i=2:*] "y.csv"  using 1:i  with linespoints
```

[image: Plot of all columns]

I can set up a function to fit with the following:-

```
  sig(x) = 1 / (1+exp(-x))       ; # Appears stable enough in gnuplot
  A = 0.6                        ; # Sigmoid Amplitude
  B = 0.2                        ; # Sigmoid offset
  C = 6                          ; # Center shift on displayed X axis
  K = 1                          ; # Shape factor
  ssig(x) = B + A*sig(K*(x-C))   ; # Fit to this
```

And, I can fit to the first data column with:-

```
 fit ssig(x)  "y.csv"  using 1:2  via A,B,C,K
```

But I can't work out the syntax of how to automatically do this over all the columns like I can for plotting.  I was expecting something like

```
fit [1:-1:i=2:*]  ssig(x)  "y.csv"  using 1:i  via A,B,C,K
```

would iterate over the columns.  I just don't understand the multi-branch syntax,  and guess I am missing some simple concept.
Many thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, may I ask you to clarify?
Do you want to perform an independent fit over all data sets, i.e. do you want to obtain something like `A_1, B_1, C_1, K_1` for the first set, `A_2, B_2, C_2, K_2` for the second and so on? Or do you want to perform a multi-branch fit, where some of the fit parameters are the same for all data sets (e.g. `A` and `K` might have some global meaning), while others have individual values for each data set (e.g. `B_1, B_2, B_3...`)?

Comment: I think I want a multi-branch fit.  A single set of `A, B, C, K` to best fit all the runs of the experiment, to the function.

Comment: I have the impression that you are using the term `multi-branch fit` in a wrong way. It would mean that you have two (or more) functions, that share some (but not all!) common parameters. For example you might fit `f_1(x) = B_1 + A*sig(K*(x-C_1))` to the first data set, `f_2(x) = B_2 + A*sig(K*(x-C_2))` to the second one and so on. (Note that the functions depend on the same `A` and `K`, but different `B`'s and `C`'s!) But according to your comment you just want to use all data points for one single function – I provided an answer for that.

Comment: Many thanks @Eldrad.  I think I became mislead down the multi-branch path while reading the GNUPlot manual.  It is rather a short section, and was beginning to think I missed something elsewhere, hence this post.  I could not see how tables might help, and was expecting something more independent like I had used in the past.  I hope this page helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you are actually not searching for a multi-branch fit, but you want to merge all columns into one single data set and perform a fit using all data points at the same time. This can be achieved quite easily by reshaping the data file into a datablock first:

```
set datafile separator ","
set table $FITDATA
plot for [i=2:*] "y.csv" u 1:i
unset table
unset datafile separator
sig(x) = 1 / (1+exp(-x))       ; # Appears stable enough in gnuplot
A = 0.6                        ; # Sigmoid Amplitude
B = 0.2                        ; # Sigmoid offset
C = 6                          ; # Center shift on displayed X axis
K = 1                          ; # Shape factor
ssig(x) = B + A*sig(K*(x-C))   ; # Fit to this
set fit errorvariables
fit ssig(x) $FITDATA u 1:2 via A,B,C,K
```

In the datablock the columns are separated by tabs, not comma, therefore one has to revert the `datafile separator` to default while fitting, and change it back again for plotting. Maybe someone else has a cleaner solution for this. `set fit errorvariables` saves the fit errors, so that they can be used for the plot title later.

```
set datafile separator ","
set datafile columnheaders
set key autotitle columnheader
set key top left
set key title "Run"
set xrange [1:12]
set xlabel "Dilution (Proportional to log([]) )"
set ylabel "Response"

plot for [i=2:*] "y.csv" u 1:i w lp, \
ssig(x) lc black lw 3 t "fit", \
keyentry t sprintf("A = %.3f ± %.3f", A, A_err), \
keyentry t sprintf("B = %.3f ± %.3f", B, B_err), \
keyentry t sprintf("C = %.3f ± %.3f", C, C_err), \
keyentry t sprintf("K = %.3f ± %.3f", K, K_err)
```

[image]

Comment: So the trick is to use a dummy run of `plot` to load and reformat the data.  `print $FITDATA` nicely shows the reformated data as a whole set of x,y points, just right for `fit` which will default to processing over the whole loaded data set as I wanted.  The placement of the table loading commands and the fitting commands can be moved around as desired, to suit coding style for a tidy solution.